# add validations before returning observable in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, validation, rxjs

Everytime the button is clicke and if If modelform is invalid then return notification message and not proceed to creating a user (createUser).

it should only proceed on returning this.accountService.create if there is no form validation error

Is the function cleanly and correctly implemented ? is there some major problem that causes the issue ? Thanks.

where do I put the checkInputs validations that if there is validation error it should not proceed on this.accountService.create

#html code

```
 <button #createUserBtn mat-flat-button color="primary" >Create
                    User</button>
```

#code

```
@ViewChild('createUserBtn', { static: true, read: ElementRef })
  button: ElementRef;


  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    fromEvent(this.button.nativeElement, 'click')
      .pipe(
        tap(x => x),
        exhaustMap(ev => {
          return this.createUser();
        })
      )
      .pipe(tap(x => x))
      .subscribe(this.handleResponse());
  }

  createUser(): Observable<any> {
    this.checkInputs();
    this.isInProgress = true;
    this.modelForm.markAllAsTouched();
    return this.accountService.create(this.modelForm.value).pipe(
        finalize(() => (this.isInProgress = false))
    );
  }

  handleResponse(): any {
    return {
      next: res => {
        this.notificationService.showSuccess('User has been created successfully.');
        this._router.navigate(['settings/user']);
      },
      error: err => {
        this.notificationService.showError('Something went wrong, Try again later.');
        this.isInProgress = false;
      },
      complete: () => this.isInProgress = false
    };
  }

  checkInputs() {
    if(this.userStatus == 'USER_ON_NO_ACCOUNT') {

      if(!this.modelForm.get('firstName').value) {
        this.notificationService.showError('First Name is required.');
        return;
      }

      if(!this.modelForm.get('lastName').value) {
        this.notificationService.showError('Last Name is required.');
        return;
      }

      if(!this.modelForm.get('companyName').value) {
        this.notificationService.showError('Company Name is required.');
        return;
      }
    }
    
    if(!this.modelForm.get('roleId').value) {
      this.notificationService.showError('Security Role is required.');
      return;
    }

    if(this.modelForm.get('roleId').value && this.modelForm.get('roleId').value !== 7 && !this.modelForm.get('isSso').value) {
      this.notificationService.showError('SSO is required.');
      return;
    }

    if(this.modelForm.get('roleId').value && this.modelForm.get('isSso').value && this.modelForm.get('isSso').value ==='Yes' && !this.modelForm.get('ssocredentials').value) {
      this.notificationService.showError('SSO Credential is required.');
      return;
    }

    if(this.modelForm.get('isSso').value ==='No') {
      this.modelForm.get('ssocredentials').setValue(null);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the `invalid` check before `this.accountService.create(this.modelForm.value)`, but you have to change the `click` event handler to be like the following:

- There is no need to handle the `click` event this way, and instead, you can add the event handler directly from the template:

```html
<button mat-flat-button color="primary" (click)="createUser()">
  Create User
</button>
```

- There is no need to chain the `createUser` with the other observables, the and same for `handleResponse`. Instead, you can subscribe to the `accountService.create` function within `createUser` method and handle the `success` and `fail` within it also, like the following:

```js
createUser(): void {
  this.checkInputs();
  this.isInProgress = true;
  this.modelForm.markAllAsTouched();

  // here you can check if the form is valid or not:
  if (this.modelForm.invalid) return;

  this.accountService.create(this.modelForm.value)
    .pipe(
      // take(1) is used to complete the observable after the result comes.
      take(1),
      catchError((err) => {
        this.notificationService.showError(
          'Something went wrong, Try again later.'
        );
        this.isInProgress = false;
        return EMPTY;
      }),
      finalize(() => (this.isInProgress = false))
    )
    .subscribe((res) => {
      this.notificationService.showSuccess(
        'User has been created successfully.'
      );
      this._router.navigate(['settings/user']);
    });
}
```

- You can remove the `ngAfterViewInit` block, `handleResponse` method, and the `button` `@ViewChild`, because the above `createUser` will handle that, and `complete` the observable directly after receiving the result from the service.